# RabbitMQ Error: unable to connect to nodes : nodedown

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

I am trying to do clustering using two Rhel instances. I am able to ping each other and even when i am trying to use command `empd -names`, i get it is up and running on 4369.When i am use the command as `sudo rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@ip-10-23-20-36` i am getting the below error ensuring as well to i am stop_app first..

```
sudo rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@ip-10-23-20-36
```

Clustering node 'rabbit@ip-10-23-20-36' with 'rabbit@ip-10-23-209-142' ...
Error: unable to connect to nodes ['rabbit@ip-10-23-209-142']: nodedown

## DIAGNOSTICS

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@ip-10-23-209-142']

rabbit@ip-10-23-209-142:
  * unable to connect to epmd (port 4369) on ip-10-23-209-142: nxdomain (non-existing domain)

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-80@ip-10-23-20-36'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: u7nRIpJ40Fd356iLbkDO6Q==

Things I already tried:

1. Checked the cookie name,which is same in both instances using
        `sudo cat /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie`.
2. Changed the epmd port as well `export  ERL_EMPD_PORT=4370`
3. `netstat -an |grep 4369 | grep -i listen`
4. Changing the hostnames as well in GUI of plugin management.
5. Changed owner and permission also using

   ```
   sudo chown rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
   sudo chmod 400 /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
   ```
6. Add port

   ```
   sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 4369 --syn -j ACCEPT
   ```
7. sudo rabbitmqctl status

   ```
   {listeners,[{clustering,25672,"::"},{amqp,5672,"::"}]},
   ```

*IP-Adresses are sample adrresses.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As the error message says, your hostnames do not resolve:

```
rabbit@ip-10-23-209-142: * unable to connect to epmd (port 4369) on ip-10-23-209-142: nxdomain (non-existing domain)
```

You need to declare those hostnames in your DNS or in `/etc/hosts` on both hosts. You can then test the name resolution is working by using eg. ping(1):

```
ping ip-10-23-209-142 # from ip-10-23-20-36
```

Comment: Thanks Jean.So bad of me.Forgot to check that.

Comment: "systemctl restart rabbitmq-server.service" solved the same issue I had.

Comment: Can you mark the question as answered since it is the correct solution?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error like that today and the suggestion is meaningless.

So, firstly, you should check its log at /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbitmq@[your hostname].log or you waste your time. Then you can see what's happened there.

In my case, it reported an error in file /var/db/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@www/cluster_nodes.config

```
 Error description:


{error,{cannot_read_file,"/var/db/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@www/cluster_nodes.config",
                        {1,erl_parse,["syntax error before: ","'@'"]}}}
```

So, I just remove this folder /var/db/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@www and restart the service and it works like a charm

Comment: Where is this log file? I cannot locate it anywhere.

Comment: It may be a bit different on your system. Please, check the its docs/configuration file for more deails. https://www.rabbitmq.com/logging.html

Answer (score 2):

Below command fixed the issue:

```
sudo service rabbitmq-server start
```

Reason:

- Having rabbitmq on both Windows & its Linux subsystem (Ubututu 18, downloaded from Microsoft Store) on same machine.
- Uninstall rabbitmq on Windows OS
- Ran the above command

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a bit late but it can help some.
I've had the same error and I've writen in the /etc/hosts file my ip and a custom name.
Then restart rabbitmq server and it has worked for me.